# What does this proof mean?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, proof-theory

I'm having difficulty reading these proofs,

> **Definition 1** $V$ is an *NP-verifier* for $L$ if $V$ is polynomial-time in the length of the first input and that the following two properties hold:
>
> - (completeness) If $x \in L$, $\exists \pi: V(x,\pi) = 1$.
> - (soundness) If $x \notin L$, $\forall \pi : V(x,\pi) = 0$.
>
> [(Original image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3vY9.png)

so the completeness one would be, if $x$ is an element of $L$ (part of the set $L$), there exists a $\pi$ that is ????

and the soundness one is if $x$ is not an element of $L$ (not part of the set $L$), every $\pi$ is not ????

Can anyone help me fill in the missing pieces?

Thank you

Comment: Reading the Wikipedia entry on a NP verify should help. Digits $1$ and $0$ may stand for $yes$ or $true $ and $no $ respectively.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)

Comment: okay so am I correct in saying the completeness one would be, if x is an element of L, there exists a pi where function V(x, pi) = false ?

Comment: That's not a proof at all. It's a definition.

Comment: sorry you're right. would the definition be correct: if x is an element of L, there exists a pi where function V(x, pi) = false

Answer (score 3):

Intuitively, you should think of $V$ as an algorithm that, given $x$ and an alleged reason $\pi$ for believing that $x\in L$, either says "Yes, I'm convinced that $x\in L$" (coded as output $1$) or says "I'm not convinced; $x$ might be in $L$, but this $\pi$ doesn't convince me" (coded as output $0$).  Completeness says that, if $x\in L$, then there is some way to convince $V$ to believe it, i.e., some $\pi$ that will make $V$ produce the output $1$ (meaning "I'm convinced").  Soundness says that, if $x\notin L$, then nothing can fool $V$ into thinking that $x\in L$, i.e., no matter what alleged reason $\pi$ we provide, $V$ will give output $0$ (meaning "I'm not convinced").

Comment: thank you that was very clear. so in that case, π is a variable representing a reason?

Comment: $\pi$ is certainly a variable here.  Notice that it is quantified in both Completeness and Soundness; only variables can be quantified.  As for "representing a reason", that's how I think of it.  Other people say "witness" rather than "reason"; their intuitive picture is that $\pi$ testifies to the claim that $x\in L$.